# Redirect a visitor to a specific page if he is from a specific country - HTML PAGE

Tags: javascript, html

I wonder if there is a javascript code that verifies the country of the visitor, and if it is not from the countries allowed to enter the page, it redirects it to another page

Thank you all

Comment: Client-side JavaScript on its own has no way to determine the "country of the visitor", you would need to find some API that you can request that info from first of all.

Comment: This might help you https://developers.cloudflare.com/workers/examples/country-code-redirect/

Answer (score 0):

I'd opt for using CloudFlare to handle these redirects. Doing this through JavaScript is a poor choice and adds additional server load.

If you must complete the task with your JavaScript; there's Geolocation API and there's a ton of websites that offer an API for lookups (they'll do the heavy lifting determining where things are on a map). As mentioned obtaining the actual IP in client-sided JavaScript is not possible, such should be obtained through server-sided connection events.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I deal with Cloudflare, but the process of dealing with countries is only banning, not redirecting

Comment: No it's not! Go to rules -> redirect it's in beta right now use a custom filter expression.

Comment: 301 is actually the permanent redirect. [301 docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/301): *"301 Moved Permanently redirect status response code indicates that the requested resource has been definitively moved to the URL given by the Location headers."*
[302 docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/302): *"302 Found redirect status response code indicates that the resource requested has been temporarily moved to the URL given by the Location header."*

Comment: Yes! Sorry, that is a huge bad on my behalf, been a minute since I've thrown the redirect code. Thanks for that catch I'll adjust.

Comment: Just remember to set redirect as temporary status till you're sure, it's very annoying when you 301 a user and you make small changes cause they will remember the status for a long time. In other words you won't be able to clear their cache if you mess redirects up so status 302 will ensure they'll keep checking if this is true.

Comment: Dear, how do I make the option to select the country, then activate the 301 or 302 redirect

Comment: The side panel of CloudFlare once you've selected your domain, there's a side-panel you want to navigate to Rules -> Redirect Rules; Now all you need to do is create a rule.

Comment: I know this, but the question is where do I specify the specific country to which the Rules will apply

Comment: Custom filter expression toggled, you'd change the field to Country. Then select operator/value as you see fit. Below you'd select the URL redirect link. If you want more than one country to go to this redirect link then you can above select OR and add another country.

Comment: I honestly don't know where to find this option